# Link: unknown props found: onClick

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using react with nextjs. When I try to add onClick to link I am getting an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'next/link'

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <Link href="/index" onClick={()=>console.log("sdf")}><a>Home</a></Link>
        <Link href="/about"><a>About</a></Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Isn't this how onClick is added to links in reactjs? or is this something to do with nextjs

Comment: add the `onClick` to the `a` element, not the `Link` element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is the way how to add a handler to link in React.js. But, this is a problem of `Link` component from Next.js. This `Link` component doesn’t have any `onClick` prop. It even overrides `onClick` prop of its child with its own implementation.

So, this also wouldn’t work:

```
<Link href="/index">
  <a onClick={() => console.log('Does not work')}>Home</a>
</Link>
```

The simple solution could be to nest `onClick` handler into another element like this:

```
<Link href="/index">
  <a>
    <span onClick={() => console.log('It works')}>Home</span>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Or to wrap `Link` with the other element, `span` for example:

```
<span onClick={() => console.log('It also works')}>
  <Link href="/index">Home</Link>
</span>
```

There is an open issue about it on Github: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1490.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `onCLick` with `onClick`

Comment: that was a typo. even with the correct l it is not working.

Comment: what does it say now?